# workflow definition cache limit of 1000 has been reached

Tags: .net, powershell, workflow, workflow-foundation

PowerShell Related: When attempting to run a script which has a few workflow functions and has worked just fine in the past; all of a sudden it is throwing the following error:

"The workflow '' could not be started: The workflow definition has been recycled, because the workflow definition cache limit of 1000 has been reached. Import the workflow or module again, and then 
retry the operation."

I haven't found a single thing via Google or Bing on how to handle/clear this cache. I assume its possibly within the .NET Windows Workflow foundation space which is called when PowerShell invokes a workflow. I just can't dig up the information. I'm having to manually step through the script and recall the functions prior to the step they run at in order to keep things working.

How can this cache be cleared or managed?

Comment: All of a sudden probably means after installation of KB4462926? Try uninstalling this patch. Several users [reported a problem](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/9nlg60/very_weird_and_strange_workflow_issue/) with this patch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is been going on since the Monthly Rollup of October 2018. The .NET Workflow module can no longer handle more then 1000 items. After deinstalling the October patch (https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/4462926/windows-8-update-kb4462926) the issue was solved.

And it looks like the issue is not yet solved in the November patch.